# 関数において返り値を2つ以上指定する方法

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-xでプログラミングをしていると、関数の返り値は1つしか指定できないことに気付きました。返り値が2つ以上あった場合はどのように指定すれば良いのでしょうか？
以下のchangeTwoSpritePositionX()は、2つのSpriteのX座標を指定された値に変更し、2つのSpriteを返しくれる関数です。正常に動作させるには、どのような修正を加えればよいでしょうか？詳しい方、ご教示ください。

```
void changeTwoSpritePositonX(Sprite *spriteA,Sprite *spriteB,float positionX){
  spriteA->setPosition(Point(positionX,spriteA->getPositionY()));
  spriteB->setPosition(Point(positionX,spriteB->getPositionY()));
  // return ここでspriteAとspriteBを返したい
}
```

Comment: ポインター渡ししたspriteAとspriteBを変更しているので、返す必要は無いのでは？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、複数の戻り値を指定することは現在のC++ではできません。提示されたコードの場合は、ポインターが引数となっているためそのままでも利用できます。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int * i)
{
   *i = 6;
}
int main()
{
   int * int_ptr = new int(5);
   cout << *int_ptr << endl;
   f(int_ptr);
   cout << *int_ptr << endl;
}
```

このように上記のコードを実行すればほかの方の回答が理解できると思います。

とりあえず以下が元の質問への回答です。
structなどを利用することにより、戻り値に複数に要素を持たせることができます。

1.container(例えばvectorなど)に格納して返す

```
std::vector<Sprite*> return_val;
return_val.push_back(spriteA);
return_val.push_back(spriteB);
return(return_val);
```

ただし、containerにポインターを格納するのは一般的に良い考えではありません。なお要素はoperator[]でアクセスできます。また、iteratorなどでもアクセスできます。

2.std::pairもしくはstd::tuppleを返す

```
return(std::make_pair(spriteA,spriteB));
```

もしくは

```
return(std::make_tuple(spriteA,spriteB));
```

また、pairの場合は.first、.second、tupleの場合はgetで要素にアクセスできます。

3.struct、classを使う

```
struct sprite_ptr_container
{
   sprite * _ptr1;
   sprite * _ptr2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alphaさんが仰っていますが、spriteAとspriteBのポインターを渡しているので返さなくても変更されています。spriteAとspriteBは、中身が変わっているのでcinやprintf等でご確認ください。

後、2つの値を返すのは無理なので、ポインタや参照というものがあるのです。（それ以外の理由もありますが！）

Comment: どうしても返したいようでしたら、Kazuki Tsunemiさんの方法しかないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

"複数の戻り値を関数で返すこと" だけを考えると、C++ で行うのは STL の`std::pair` や `std::tuple` を使う方法です。

```
std::pair<int, int> double_result()
{
    return std::make_pair(1, 10);
}

int a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = double_result();
```

のように、複数の結果を `std::pair` でラップし、`std::tie` 関数で取り出すことをよく行っています。

Answer (score 0):

配列を返すか返値用の構造体を定義して返すといいと思います